# How to retrieve multiple user's recent videos using the YouTube API v3

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api

Digging into the v3 YouTube API for the first time and struggling a bit. I've got an array of channel IDs:

```
$channel_ids = [
    'UC6nSFpj9HTCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB',
    'UC6nSFpjSEBUCZ5t-N3Ra3-HB',
    'UC6nrst90rsd3Z5t-N3Ra3-HC',
    'UC6nSFpjd329th0rt-tuTH3-HA',
    etc...
]
```

I want to retrieve videos released by these channels over the last three days with as few http requests as possible.

The data I need returned is:

- channel title (`channelTitle`)
- video id (`videoID`)
- video title (`title`)
- video age (`publishedAt`)
- video length (?)
- video views (?)
- any channel logos would be nice, but I can live without

I couldn't figure out how to make `/search` return the video length or views. `/search` also seemed like it could only do one channel ID at a time. `/videos` won't work because it requires a video id, not a channel id. `playlistItems` might work, but requires me to look up the channel's `videos` playlist and store it, which = one extra call * number of channels. Maybe that's how Google wants you to do it? That's why I'm asking here.

Some general guidance is all I'm looking for, not looking for anyone to write the code for me.

FWIW, I'm working in PHP.

Comment: Yeah, so, umm... after digging around... google didn't design this API to limit requests to their servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For each channel you'll need to call Search:list using the publishedAfter parameter for 3 days ago. Store the videoIDs from the results.
2. Now batch call Videos:list with the id parameter containing up to 50 videoIDs at a time and the part parameter with snippet, contentDetails and statistics. That will give you the data results you're asking for.

You could also automate this using a plugin like Video Blogster.

Comment: I'm right in the middle of doing exactly what you described. There are going to be a lot of calls to the youtube API, unfortunately. There's just no way around it. The "Video Blogster" plugin you mentioned seems to be a WP plugin. Do you know of any PHP libraries that simulate that procedure?